# How do I search something on the sql database without typing the name of the whole thing that I am looking for

Tags: python, flask

I have a database full of car Models. If I have a car brand like toyota my table has Toyot camry, Toyota avalon, toyota corolla. So I have a webage that allows the user to search for a car. So it the user types in toyota and clicks search. all the toyotas sgould pop up. so it they search Toyota, Toyota camry, Toyota avalon, toyota corollashould pop up. I am using sql and flask
this is my code below but its not working.

```
  record = db.session.query(Car).filter_by(cars = form.name.data).all()
```

Comment: what is your database? MongoDB?

Comment: no i am using sql @Marya

Comment: I would use the com `" SELECT * FROM car WHERE cars = {} ".format(form.name.data)`
then I execute the command.

Comment: What do you mean by *its not working*? What error it produces? What is `Car` (what fields does it have?)

Comment: well the above code will search for the exact car model match. I want it to  be presented with a string and search for every single car in the database that starts with the presented string @sudden_appearance

Comment: Then you need to use SQL's `ILIKE` not `==`. Simplest example (assuming `Car.cars` is valid field) goes like this `db.session.query(Car).filter_by(Car.cars.ilike(form.name.data).all()`

Comment: you can use from "Fulltext and thesaurus" like this link:

https://voiceofthedba.com/2013/01/21/full-text-search-thesaurus/

Comment: albeit you must run Fulltext service before